# Search Twitter Users in app

Tags: java, android, twitter-fabric

I've gotten to the point in my app where I've integrated the Twitter API into my project using Fabric and have a Twitter login which redirects to a blank activity. I want to have a search bar at the top of this activity which searches for Twitter users (only users). How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You have access to the API, so have you read the documentation to see how to search users?

Comment: I installed the twitter kit into android studio using fabric, but I believe in order to use the REST api I would need to use retrofit or something (I can be totally wrong about this), so I'm seeing if it's possible using the kit (and having some difficulty in that regard, haha).

Answer (score 0):

You need query for search twitter. see below sample.

private static final String SEARCH_QUERY = "almounir"; //the username or Hshgtag

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout. activity_main);

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
//lv.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.loading)); d'ont forget to add loading pic 

SearchTimeline searchTimeline = new SearchTimeline.Builder().query(SEARCH_QUERY).build();

final TweetTimelineListAdapter timelineAdapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter(this, searchTimeline);

lv.setAdapter(timelineAdapter);
}
```

some another sample [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/how-build-android-twitter) [source code](https://github.com/Rockncoder/TwitterSearchTutorial) [sample](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-twitter-search-app-project-setup--mobile-13755)

Comment: Thank you! That's a great start. My question is, how do I make it so the results are only usernames?